Http failure response for https://api.ipify.org/?format=json: 0 Unknown Error
I am not able to understand but the api.ipify.org is failing in Firefox and Safari browser. Its working fine in Chrome browser but don't know why failing in Firefox and Safari.
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var ip = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://api.ipify.org");
Console.WriteLine($"My public IP address is: {ip}");



it looks that it is console log of browser, are you sure about report you sent?

By the way, you should make user to send request if your application is a web application. In order to do this, make a api call by js whenever you need users data.
if you want to get users IP for your server, simply in the requests which user send, you can get the IP from header of the request.

I used PostMan and the url was ok so I used Postman's converter and there is the codes:
C#
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://api.ipify.org");
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

JS:
const requestOptions = {
  method: "GET",
  redirect: "follow"
};

fetch("https://api.ipify.org", requestOptions)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((result) => console.log(result))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));

Jquery:
var settings = {
  "url": "https://api.ipify.org",
  "method": "GET",
  "timeout": 0,
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});

